# error during upgrade postgres version -11 to 12 (old and new pg_controldata WAL segment sizes are invalid or do not match)

Tags: postgresql, upgrade

we are facing error during postgres upgrade version from 11 to 12 .
Please suggest what I do to resolve this issue.

```
Error:
Performing Consistency Checks on Old Live Server
------------------------------------------------
Checking cluster versions                                   ok

old and new pg_controldata WAL segment sizes are invalid or do not match
Failure, exiting
bash-4.1$ 
.....................
command:
/usr/pgsql-12/bin/pg_upgrade --old-datadir /var/lib/pgsql/11/data/ --new-datadir /var/lib/pgsql/12/data/ --old-bindir /usr/pgsql-11/bin/ --new-bindir /usr/pgsql-12/bin/ --check
```